# Keras model unable to call predict when passed through function

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras

I am loading in many Keras models like so:

```
from keras import backend as K # Tensorflow backend
from MiscFunctions import *
def main():
    for i in range(...):
        K.clear_session() # Needed to speed up model loading
        model = load_model(...)
        model._make_predict_function()
main()
```

However, I have a function call later in the script that takes a model input and outputs a prediction from that model.

```
length = get_length(model, ...)
```

And here is the shortened code for `get_length`

```
def get_length(model, ...):
    ...
    # input_vector is the correct size
    return model.predict(np.asarray(input_vector).reshape(1,1,len(input_vector)))
```

Except the `prediction` method call gives me the error:

```
tensorflow.python.framework.errors_impl.NotFoundError: FetchOutputs node dense_1/Softmax:0: not found
Exception tensorflow.python.framework.errors_impl.InvalidArgumentError: InvalidArgumentError() in <bound method _Callable.__del__ of <tensorflow.python.client.session._Callable object at 0x7f619b8c7e10>> ignored
```

I suspect the `K.clear_session()` line may be causing the problem, but I need to clear the session to speed up the model loadings. How do I resolve this issue?

Answer (score 0):

For loading model efficiently, make it global and load it into another function, so that you don't have to load it again and again. After making it global, it will be accessible in main function:

```
def load_model():

    global model

    json_file = open('model.json', 'r')
    model_json = json_file.read()
    model = model_from_json(model_json)
    model.load_weights("model.h5")
    model._make_predict_function()
```